# Why is $[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}}=P[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B'}}\rightarrow\alpha'_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P_{ij}\alpha_{i}$ obvious?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the middle of looking into one of the theorems regarding **coordinates** a part of the proof of the one that I was reviewing at that time—which is presented below—puzzled me in that it was not **so obvious** to me—which means the approach that I took failed(=not enough) to sound *obvious*—that (1) inevitably leads to (2). A lucid proof upon this relationship would be appreciated.

> *Proof.* Let $\mathfrak{B}$ consist of the vectors $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$. If $\mathfrak{B'}=\{\alpha'_{1},\ldots,\alpha'_{n}\}$ is an ordered basis of V for which 
>   $$[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}}=P[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B'}}\quad\cdots\quad(1)$$ is valid, **it is clear that** $$\alpha'_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P_{ij}\alpha_{i}\quad\cdots\quad(2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha_j' = 0\alpha_1' + \dots + 0\alpha_{j-1}' + 1\alpha_j' + 0\alpha_{j+1}' + \dots + 0\alpha_n'$, so $[\alpha_j']_{\mathcal{B}'} = e_j$. Therefore,

$$[\alpha_j']_{\mathcal{B}} = P[\alpha_j']_{\mathcal{B}'} = Pe_j = \begin{bmatrix} P_{1j}\\ P_{2j}\\ \vdots\\ P_{nj}\end{bmatrix}$$

so $\alpha_j' = P_{1j}\alpha_1 + P_{2j}\alpha_2 + \dots + P_{nj}\alpha_n = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nP_{ij}\alpha_i$.